# If $d(x,y)$ is a metric, how does the following inequality apply?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality, metric-spaces

I'm interested if someone can formally type out why this is. I thought it was trivial, but the professor wanted a more detailed explanation:

$${d(x,y)\over {1+d(x,y)}}\leq \frac{d(x,z)+d(z,y)}{1+d(x,z)+d(z,y)} $$ I am fully aware the triangle inequality applies to metrics, where do I go from here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that the function

$$f(x) = \frac{x}{1+x} $$

is increasing on $[0,+\infty[$. Indeed

$$f'(x) = \frac{1}{(1+x)^2} \geq 0$$

So $f$ keep the order. And as $d(x,y) \leq d(x,z)+d(z,y)$ you have that

$$f( d(x,y) ) \leq f( d(x,z)+d(z,y)) $$

Answer (score 1):

HINT: In effect you need to prove that if $0\le a\le b$, then

$$\frac{a}{1+a}\le\frac{b}{1+b}\;.$$

This is true if and only if $a(1+b)\le b(1+a)$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Consider the function $f(t) = \frac{t}{1  +t}$, and show that it is monotonically increasing at $[0, \infty)$.

Answer (score 1):

$f(u) = u/(1+u) = 1 - 1/(1+u)$ and $f'(u) = +1/(1+u)^2$. Hence $f$ is increasing on the domain $[0,\infty)$. Use this result and the triangle inequality on $d$ to conclude your inequality.